# Introduce calculated values in a new column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to introduce a new column where it holds the calculated sum of next three Periods.

This is the sample data

```
Company Value   Period
------- -----   ------
MGT     9       1401
MGT     2       1402
MGT     3       1403
MGT     4       1404
MGT     5       1405
MGT     6       1406
MGT     7       1407
MGT     8       1408
MGT     9       1409
MGT     10      1410
MGT     11      1411
MGT     12      1412
MGT     3       1501
```

This is the Expected data

```
Company Value   Period  New_Column
------- -----   ------  ----------
MGT     9       1401    9
MGT     2       1402    12
MGT     3       1403    15
MGT     4       1404    18
MGT     5       1405    21
MGT     6       1406    24
MGT     7       1407    27
MGT     8       1408    30
MGT     9       1409    33
MGT     10      1410    26
MGT     11      1411    15
MGT     12      1412    3
MGT     3       1501    0
```

The New_Column contains the addition of values from next three months.
For Example consider column Period **1403 (March'14)** where the Value is **3**, the New_Column should now have the addition of values from next three months 
**i.e., values of [1404(April'14) + 1404(May'14) + 1405(June'14)]** [4 + 5 + 6] **= 15**

Comment: Generally, it's a bad idea to store data that can be easily calculated from other data. Also, it might be simpler to store period as a date - the first of the month, say.

Comment: @Strawberry I have thousands of such data and would like to use it for analysis.

Comment: any programming language you'd want to use to achieve this?

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server` that makes a big difference, but you have added tags for both.

Comment: I am fine with any :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code in MS SQL Server 2008

```
select t1.Company, t1.value value, t1.period period, 
isnull(t2.value,0) 
+ isnull(t3.value,0)
+ isnull(t4.value,0) New_Column
  from @NOA t1
     left join @NOA t2 on (t1.period % 100 < 12 and t1.period = t2.period - 1)
                       or (t1.period % 100 >= 12 and t1.period = t2.period - 89)
     left join @NOA t3 on (t1.period % 100 < 11 and t1.period = t3.period - 2)
                       or (t1.period % 100 >= 11 and t1.period = t3.period - 90)
     left join @NOA t4 on (t1.period % 100 < 10 and t1.period = t4.period - 3)
                       or (t1.period % 100 >= 10 and t1.period = t4.period - 91)
```

Delivers the result expected

```
Company Value   Period  New_Column
------- -----   ------  ----------
MGT     9       1401    9
MGT     2       1402    12
MGT     3       1403    15
MGT     4       1404    18
MGT     5       1405    21
MGT     6       1406    24
MGT     7       1407    27
MGT     8       1408    30
MGT     9       1409    33
MGT     10      1410    26
MGT     11      1411    15
MGT     12      1412    3
MGT     3       1501    0
```

Thank you @all :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (company CHAR(3) NOT NULL
 ,dt DATE NOT NULL
 ,value INT NOT NULL
 ,PRIMARY KEY(company,dt)
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 ('MGT',20140101,9),
 ('MGT',20140201,2),
 ('MGT',20140301,3),
 ('MGT',20140401,4),
 ('MGT',20140501,5),
 ('MGT',20140601,6),
 ('MGT',20140701,7),
 ('MGT',20140801,8),
 ('MGT',20140901,9),
 ('MGT',20141001,10),
 ('MGT',20141101,11),
 ('MGT',20141201,12),
 ('MGT',20150101,3);

 mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +---------+------------+-------+
 | company | dt         | value |
 +---------+------------+-------+
 | MGT     | 2014-01-01 |     9 |
 | MGT     | 2014-02-01 |     2 |
 | MGT     | 2014-03-01 |     3 |
 | MGT     | 2014-04-01 |     4 |
 | MGT     | 2014-05-01 |     5 |
 | MGT     | 2014-06-01 |     6 |
 | MGT     | 2014-07-01 |     7 |
 | MGT     | 2014-08-01 |     8 |
 | MGT     | 2014-09-01 |     9 |
 | MGT     | 2014-10-01 |    10 |
 | MGT     | 2014-11-01 |    11 |
 | MGT     | 2014-12-01 |    12 |
 | MGT     | 2015-01-01 |     3 |
 +---------+------------+-------+

 SELECT x.*
      , COALESCE(SUM(y.value),0) new_val 
   FROM my_table x 
   LEFT
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.company = x.company 
    AND y.dt BETWEEN x.dt + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND x.dt + INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
  GROUP 
     BY x.company
      , x.dt;
 +---------+------------+-------+---------+
 | company | dt         | value | new_val |
 +---------+------------+-------+---------+
 | MGT     | 2014-01-01 |     9 |       9 |
 | MGT     | 2014-02-01 |     2 |      12 |
 | MGT     | 2014-03-01 |     3 |      15 |
 | MGT     | 2014-04-01 |     4 |      18 |
 | MGT     | 2014-05-01 |     5 |      21 |
 | MGT     | 2014-06-01 |     6 |      24 |
 | MGT     | 2014-07-01 |     7 |      27 |
 | MGT     | 2014-08-01 |     8 |      30 |
 | MGT     | 2014-09-01 |     9 |      33 |
 | MGT     | 2014-10-01 |    10 |      26 |
 | MGT     | 2014-11-01 |    11 |      15 |
 | MGT     | 2014-12-01 |    12 |       3 |
 | MGT     | 2015-01-01 |     3 |       0 |
 +---------+------------+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

**Your Table Definition**

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
Company nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
Value int NOT NULL,
Period char(4) NOT NULL  
);

INSERT INTO TestTable
(Company, Value, Period)
VALUES
('MGT', 9, 1401),
('MGT', 11,1402),
('MGT', 5, 1403),
('MGT', 6, 1404);
```

**And then do the query as follows**

Create a temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTable AS 
(SELECT 
CAST(SUBSTRING(Period, 1, 2) AS UNSIGNED) AS Year,
CAST(SUBSTRING(Period, 3, 2) AS UNSIGNED) AS Month,
Value,
Company
FROM TestTable)
```

and directly afterwards

```
SELECT Company, Month, Year, 

Value

+

IFNULL((SELECT Value FROM TempTable SUBQUERY_02
WHERE SUBQUERY_02.Month = 
CASE 
    WHEN SUBQUERY_01.Month = 12 THEN 1 
    ELSE SUBQUERY_01.Month + 1 
END
AND SUBQUERY_02.Year =
CASE 
    WHEN SUBQUERY_01.Month = 12 THEN SUBQUERY_01.Year + 1
    ELSE SUBQUERY_01.Year
END), 0)

+

IFNULL((SELECT Value FROM TempTable SUBQUERY_03
WHERE SUBQUERY_03.Month = 
CASE 
    WHEN SUBQUERY_01.Month = 11 THEN 1 
    WHEN SUBQUERY_01.Month = 12 THEN 2 
    ELSE SUBQUERY_01.Month + 2
END
AND SUBQUERY_03.Year =
CASE 
    WHEN SUBQUERY_01.Month >= 11 THEN SUBQUERY_01.Year + 1
    ELSE SUBQUERY_01.Year
END), 0)

FROM TempTable SUBQUERY_01
```